# Pass and get variables from server for JavaScript/HTML site

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

so I need to pass and get variables from a server for my HTML Site (JavaScript). I'm trying to make a online game so I need to pass variables like names and all players online. I'm a total noob with stuff like servers so how can I get a simple server to hold variables and read and write files or something like that, because I want to create folders for accounts on the server.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to learn a server-side language like PHP, ASP.NET. Best place to start www.w3schools.com/php/‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to learn PHP. It's one of the easier server-sided languages.

You should store your data in databases. For example mysql. You will also have to learn how to do this ;-)

Use AJAX in case you want to get the data from the server while the site is already loaded. Google it ;-)

If you want to create the server yourself on your own computer instead of using one in the internet you should use something like XAMPP. It includes every program you need for the beginning without the configuration-pain ^^

Overall you will have to do a lot of learning ^^ Noobs don't create games, so stop being one ;-)

Comment: Thanks, wish me luck. :)